# Asymptotic limit of Hypergeometric function into Whittaker function.

Tags: limits, asymptotics, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I started with the differential equation
\begin{equation}
 -\sinh^2(x) \left( \frac{d^2}{dx^2} - \left( k - \frac{b}{\tanh(x)} \right)^2\right) \phi_1(x) = \lambda \phi_1(x)
\end{equation}
and found a solution involving the hypergeometric function
\begin{equation}
 \phi_1(x) = \left(1-\coth(x)\right)^{(k-|b|)/2} \left(1 +\coth(x)\right)^{-(k+|b|)/2}\text{ }_2F_1 \left( \frac{1}{2} - |b| -i \nu, \frac{1}{2} - |b|  + i \nu, k-|b|+1, \frac{1-\coth(x)}{2}   \right)\,, \qquad 0 < \nu < +\infty
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 i\nu = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+b^2-\lambda}
\end{equation}
However, I'm interested in working on a certain limit of this equation, that occurs for small $x$, in which the equation can be reduced to
\begin{equation}
  -x^2 \left( \frac{d^2}{dx^2} - \left( k - \frac{b}{x} \right)^2\right) \phi_2(x) = \lambda \phi_2(x)
\end{equation}
and we can obtain a solution in terms of the Whittaker function
\begin{equation}
 \phi_2(x) = W_{b, i\nu} (2 |k|x)
\end{equation}
From this, we would expect to see
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{x \to 0} \phi_1(x) \to \phi_2(x)
\end{equation}
But I can't seem to find a way to approximate the hypergeometric function into the Whittaker function.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: You can use https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E2 and then the hypergeometric series. Whittaker doesn't have any role here.